The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process this errors occurs while starting apache kafka server
unable to start the apache kafka The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process while starting the apache kafka
first i run the zoo keeper  using below command
.\zookeeper-server-start.bat C:\kafka\config\zookeeper.properties

and then i run the apache kafka using below command
$ bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties

below is the error which i have received
WARN Failed atomic move of C:\tmp\kafka-logs\__consumer_offsets-13\00000000000000000000.timeindex.cleaned to C:\tmp\kafka-logs\__consumer_offsets-13\00000000000000000000.timeindex.swap retrying with a non-atomic move (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils)
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\tmp\kafka-logs\__consumer_offsets-13\00000000000000000000.timeindex.cleaned -> C:\tmp\kafka-logs\__consumer_offsets-13\00000000000000000000.timeindex.swap: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
        at org.apache.kafka.server.util.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.java:136)
[2024-11-30 17:47:52,208] ERROR Failed to clean up log for __consumer_offsets-13 in dir C:\tmp\kafka-logs due to IOException (org.apache.kafka.storage.internals.log.LogDirFailureChannel)
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\tmp\kafka-logs\__consumer_offsets-13\00000000000000000000.timeindex.cleaned -> C:\tmp\kafka-logs\__consumer_offsets-13\00000000000000000000.timeindex.swap: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process at org.apache.kafka.server.util.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.java:136)


Kafka doesn't need zookeeper anymore. Do you?
